# libmysql.dll error on ruby 5.1.4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Hello i am new on ruby on rails and trying to learn. I am using the Rails 5.1.4 version and trying to connect it with mysql but it shows me Failed to load libmysql.dll error

I know this question is being asked already but none of those solutions work with this version. I tried downgrading it to version 5.0 as well but it still gives me the same error.
I have just created a new rails file with following syntax

`rails new myrubyblog -d mysql`

and when i am trying to run the rail server it shows me the error

and my database.yml looks something like this

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: password
  host: localhost
  socket: MySQL

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myrubyblog_development
```

Comment: can you please post error log?

Comment: I am really new to ruby can u tell me where can i find the error log @GaneshNavale

Comment: Mohammed, you should change question title. This title is very bad. You can find more detail in the following link that how do you ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask